# How to get Ion-select option based on previous ion-select options and should be null when first option changed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, scrollbar, angular7, ionic4

This is the ts file and HTML code(in angular 7 with ionic). It's working when one option is dependent on the previous one. But when I want to change from one city to another city, other options should be null...but for this code, the building is not changing and tried to empty it but HTML is not taking it but for the campus, it's working.

**TS File**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastController, Events, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth.service';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { dashboardFlag } from '../global';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {

  dashboard: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  headers = new HttpHeaders;
  location: any;
  slectedLocation: any;
  campusData: any;
  buildID: any;
  id = [];
  buildingID=[];
  selectedCampus: any;
  building=[];
  campID: any;
  buildingValue: any;
  getBuilding: any;
  campusValue: any;
  formSubmitted = false;
  buildingVal: any;
  constructor(private route: Router,private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private http: Http, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public toastController: ToastController, private api: AuthService, public events: Events,public events1: Events, private menu: MenuController) {

    this.events.subscribe('locationData', (data) => {
      this.location = data[0].data;
      console.log("hei");
      console.log(this.location);
    })

     this.events.publish('dash','hello in info');
    this.menu.enable(true);

    this.dashboard = formBuilder.group({
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      campus: ['', Validators.required],
      building: ['', Validators.required]

    });  
    this.headers = this.headers.set('Authorization', 'basic' + localStorage.getItem('authKey'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.dashboard);
    this.formSubmitted = true;

    if (this.dashboard.valid) {
      if(this.dashboard.value.city){
        if(this.dashboard.value.campus){
          if(this.dashboard.value.building){
      console.log(this.dashboard.value);
      this.route.navigate(['info']); 
          }else{
            this.dashboardToast();
          }
        }else{
          this.dashboardToast();
        }
      }
      else{
        this.dashboardToast();
      }
    // Process your form
    }else{
      this.dashboardToast();
    }
  }


  dashboardToast() {
    console.log("inside");
    if (this.dashboard.value.city == "") {
      if (this.dashboard.value.campus == "") {
        if (this.dashboard.value.building == "") {
          this.toastGenerate('Select City,Campus,Building');
        }
        else {
          this.toastGenerate('Select City,Campus');
        }

      }
      else {
        if (this.dashboard.value.building == "") {
          this.toastGenerate('Select City,Building');
        }
        else {
          this.toastGenerate('Select City');
        }

      }

    }
    else {
      if (this.dashboard.value.campus == "") {
        if (this.dashboard.value.building == "") {
          this.toastGenerate('Select Campus,Building');
        }
        else {
          this.toastGenerate('Select Campus');

        }
      }
      else {
        if (this.dashboard.value.building == "") {
          this.toastGenerate('Select building');
        }

      }

    }

  }


  async toastGenerate(toastMessage: string) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: toastMessage,
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
    return;
  }


  selectedCity(event) {

     this.id=[];
     this.building=[];
    this.slectedLocation = event.target.value;
    if (this.location) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.location.length; i++) {
        if (this.slectedLocation.Location === this.location[i].Location) {
          this.campusData = this.location[i].data;
          this.buildingID = [];
          for (let j = 0; j < this.campusData.length; j++) {
            this.campID = this.campusData[j]["Campus ID"];
            this.id.push(this.campID);
            // this.selectedBuilding("");
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }


  selectedBuilding(event) {
    this.building=[];
    this.selectedCampus = event.target.value
    if (this.location) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.location.length; j++) {
        this.getBuilding = this.location[j].data;
        for (let k = 0; k < this.getBuilding.length; k++) {
          if (this.selectedCampus === this.getBuilding[k]["Campus ID"]) {
            this.building.push( this.getBuilding[k]["Building Id"]);
            // this.buildingID.push(this.building);
            console.log(this.building);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<ion-content class="bg-image"  padding>

  <form class="content" [formGroup]="dashboard">
        <!-- <ion-card class="card"> -->
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>City</ion-label>
            <ion-select placeholder="Select" formControlName="city" cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!" (ionChange)="selectedCity($event)">
              <ion-select-option [value]="cityValue" *ngFor="let cityValue of location">{{ cityValue.Location }}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
        <ion-item >
            <ion-label>Campus</ion-label>
            <ion-select  placeholder="Select" formControlName="campus"  cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!" (ionChange)="selectedBuilding($event)">
              <ion-select-option [value]="campusValue" *ngFor="let campusValue of id"> {{campusValue}} </ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item >
            <ion-label>Building</ion-label>
            <ion-select  placeholder="Select" formControlName="building" cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!">
              <ion-select-option [value]="buildingValue" *ngFor="let buildingValue of building">{{buildingValue}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item> 
        </form>
        <!-- <ion-toolbar>


      </ion-card>

     <ion-button value="block" color="success">Submit</ion-button> -->
      <ion-button class="submitButton" shape="round" expand="block" padding (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**when I select a city, the other two options should be selected based on the city. It works!
    But when change city and only campus changes and building changes only after campus selection. how to make it work. I want the other two  options to be null when I change from one city to other**

Comment: In your case, what's the difference between selecting city and changing city?

Comment: Kindly clearly mention your goal

Comment: okay!!..Suppose there are two cities,Banglre and Ahmedbd. First if I select Bangalore based on city campuses are generated.Suppose B-X is selected and based on B-X campus, building options are generated. My problem is when I toggle from Bangalore to Ahmedbd, Campus and Building should become null so that I can select options based on Ahmedbd.But when i toggle to ahmedbd city is null but building is not becoming null.building is storing previous value i.e Banglre related building. i need to empty the previous state of both campus and building when i toggle between different cities